# No module named 'Adafruit_GPIO'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, adafruit

I am doing the project in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sb_zuHGmY4) with the OLED screen.

The step by step guide I followed (https://www.the-diy-life.com/diy-raspberry-pi-4-desktop-case-with-oled-stats-display/)
and I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stats.py", line 23, in <module>
    import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Adafruit_GPIO'
```

Code:

```
# Author: Tony DiCola & James DeVito
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
# THE SOFTWARE.
import time

import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_SSD1306

from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

import subprocess

# Raspberry Pi pin configuration:
RST = None     # on the PiOLED this pin isnt used
# Note the following are only used with SPI:
DC = 23
SPI_PORT = 0
SPI_DEVICE = 0

# Beaglebone Black pin configuration:
# RST = 'P9_12'
# Note the following are only used with SPI:
# DC = 'P9_15'
# SPI_PORT = 1
# SPI_DEVICE = 0

# 128x32 display with hardware I2C:
disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST)

# 128x64 display with hardware I2C:
# disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_64(rst=RST)

# Note you can change the I2C address by passing an i2c_address parameter like:
# disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_64(rst=RST, i2c_address=0x3C)

# Alternatively you can specify an explicit I2C bus number, for example
# with the 128x32 display you would use:
# disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST, i2c_bus=2)

# 128x32 display with hardware SPI:
# disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST, dc=DC, spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE, max_speed_hz=8000000))

# 128x64 display with hardware SPI:
# disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_64(rst=RST, dc=DC, spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE, max_speed_hz=8000000))

# Alternatively you can specify a software SPI implementation by providing
# digital GPIO pin numbers for all the required display pins.  For example
# on a Raspberry Pi with the 128x32 display you might use:
# disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST, dc=DC, sclk=18, din=25, cs=22)

# Initialize library.
disp.begin()

# Clear display.
disp.clear()
disp.display()

# Create blank image for drawing.
# Make sure to create image with mode '1' for 1-bit color.
width = disp.width
height = disp.height
image = Image.new('1', (width, height))

# Get drawing object to draw on image.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)

# Draw some shapes.
# First define some constants to allow easy resizing of shapes.
padding = -2
top = padding
bottom = height-padding
# Move left to right keeping track of the current x position for drawing shapes.
x = 0


# Load default font.
font = ImageFont.load_default()

# Alternatively load a TTF font.  Make sure the .ttf font file is in the same directory as the python script!
# Some other nice fonts to try: http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php
# font = ImageFont.truetype('Minecraftia.ttf', 8)

while True:

    # Draw a black filled box to clear the image.
    draw.rectangle((0,0,width,height), outline=0, fill=0)

    # Shell scripts for system monitoring from here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119126/command-to-display-memory-usage-disk-usage-and-cpu-load
    cmd = "hostname -I | cut -d\' \' -f1"
    IP = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
    cmd = "top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf \"CPU Load: %.2f\", $(NF-2)}'"
    CPU = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
    cmd = "free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf \"Mem: %s/%sMB %.2f%%\", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'"
    MemUsage = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )
    cmd = "df -h | awk '$NF==\"/\"{printf \"Disk: %d/%dGB %s\", $3,$2,$5}'"
    Disk = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell = True )

    # Write two lines of text.

    draw.text((x, top),       "IP: " + str(IP),  font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((x, top+8),     str(CPU), font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((x, top+16),    str(MemUsage),  font=font, fill=255)
    draw.text((x, top+25),    str(Disk),  font=font, fill=255)

    # Display image.
    disp.image(image)
    disp.display()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: You probably need to install the library (although it seems to be depreciated): https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, take a look at the official docs! You're missing an old library.
While you may be able to bring it in, the maintainers have actually deprecated it and suggest another https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO

> This library has been deprecated in favor of [our python3 Blinka library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Blinka). We have replaced all of the libraries that use this repo with CircuitPython libraries that are Python3 compatible, and support a [wide variety of single board/linux computers](https://circuitpython.org/blinka)!

Do take a look at the updated docs from Adafruit: https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts/python-usage-2

They have a [direct example](https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts/python-usage-2#example-code-3041202-16) showing the use of these libraries

```py
import board
import digitalio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import adafruit_ssd1306
...
```